# Problema en optimizar código para encontrar el máximo valor de un grupo de números

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, numpy, optimización

He programado un código para que me encuentre el máximo valor absoluto de un grupo de listas llamadas: **‘vector_1’, ‘vector_2’, y ‘vector_3’** respectivamente, (ojo, pero podrían ser más listas).

Dichas listas se tienen que formar a partir de una lista madre, llamada **‘vector_total’**, agrupándose en base a los siguientes criterios:

1. Deben compartir el mismo **‘tipo’**, para este caso **‘Columna’**
2. Deben compartir un **‘carácter_comun’**, en este caso: 1, 2 o 3.
3. Deben agruparse de acuerdo a los índices que comparten de acuerdo con las dos características anteriormente mencionadas.

Al final, el objetivo es crear una lista con el máximo valor absoluto de cada una de las listas, en este caso: **‘vector_1’, ‘vector_2’, y ‘vector_3’** respectivamente.

El problema es que los condicionales me limitan solo hasta **‘carácter_comun = 3’**, pero, ¿Cómo se podría automatizar para crear **‘n’** vectores ***(vector_1, ……., vector_n)*** y que funcione para ***‘carácter_común = 1, ….., n’*** ?, esto con el fin de hallar el máximo valor de un grupo de **‘n listas’.**

```
import numpy as np                                  #INDICES
#    Elemento  Tipo   CaracterComun  1(i)   2(i)   3(i)   1(j)   2(j)   3(j)   
#      [Col0]  [Col1]     [Col2]     [Col3] [Col4] [Col5] [Col6] [Col7] [Col8] 

datos = [[ 1,  'Columna',     1,       28,    29,    30,    19,    20,    21],
         [ 2,  'Columna',     1,       31,    32,    33,    22,    23,     24],
         [ 3,  'Columna',     1,       34,    35,    36,    25,    26,     27],
         [ 4,  'Columna',     2,       19,    20,    21,    10,    11,     12],
         [ 5,  'Columna',     2,       22,    23,    24,    13,    14,    15],
         [ 6,  'Columna',     2,       25,    26,    27,    16,    17,     18],
         [ 7,  'Columna',     3,       10,    11,    12,     1,     2,      3],
         [ 8,  'Columna',     3,       13,    14,    15,     4,     5,      6],
         [ 9,  'Columna',     3,       16,    17,    18,     7,     8,      9],
         [10,  'Fila',        1,       19,    20,    21,    22,    23,     24],
         [11,  'Fila',        1,       22,    23,    24,    25,    26,     27],
         [12,  'Fila',        2,       10,    11,    12,    13,    14,     15],
         [13,  'Fila',        2,       13,    14,    15,    16,    17,     18],
         [14,  'Fila',        3,        1,     2,     3,     4,     5,      6],
         [15,  'Fila',        3,        4,     5,     6,     7,     8,      9]] 

arreglo = np.array([[ 5.6, -0.1, -0.8,  5.4, -0.4, -0.5, 5.3, -0.2, -0.4,  3.6, -0.1, -0.9,  3.6,
                     -0.3, -0.7,  3.5, -0.2, -0.7,  1.3,-0.1, -0.8,  1.3, -0.2, -0.7,  1.3, -0.1, -0.7]])

vector_total = arreglo.transpose() #-- Lista madre

#--Vectores de inicialización
x_demo_1 = [] #--> Listas que contienen la característica en común para cada fila de la matriz 'datos'
x_demo_2 = []
x_demo_3 = []

indices_1 = [] #--> Listas de índices que comparten de acuerdo con: 'tipo' y 'caracter_comun'
indices_2 = []
indices_3 = []

for i in range(len(datos)):

    tipo = datos[i][1]
    caracter_comun = datos[i][2]

    if tipo == 'Columna' and caracter_comun == 1:

        x_1 = caracter_comun
        x_demo_1.append(x_1)

        indices_1.extend([datos[i][6]-1, datos[i][7]-1, datos[i][8]-1])
        vector_1 = vector_total[indices_1] #-> Vector agrupa criterios de: indices, tipo y 'caracter_comun'
        max_1 = max(abs(vector_1))

    elif tipo == 'Columna' and caracter_comun == 2:

        x_2 = caracter_comun
        x_demo_2.append(x_2)

        indices_2.extend([datos[i][6]-1, datos[i][7]-1, datos[i][8]-1])
        vector_2 = vector_total[indices_2]         
        max_2 = max(abs(vector_2))

    elif tipo == 'Columna' and caracter_comun == 3:

        x_3 = caracter_comun
        x_demo_3.append(x_2)

        indices_3.extend([datos[i][6]-1, datos[i][7]-1, datos[i][8]-1])
        vector_3 = vector_total[indices_3]        
        max_3 = max(abs(vector_3))

vector_maximos = np.array([max_1, max_2, max_3]) #--> Lista conformada por el máximo 
                                                 #    valor absoluto de cada lista: 'vector_1, 2 y 3'.
```

Agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedan aportar a este problema, saludos cordiales.

Comment: ¿Puedes usar Pandas? Lo digo porque te haría la vida mucho más sencilla...

Comment: Hasta ahora he utilizado esa librería para importar unas bases de datos almacenadas desde un excel, pero investigaré un poco más a ver que me resulta, muchas gracias .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he solucionado el problema, con Pandas podría hacerlo @FJSevilla y muchas gracias por su sugerencia, lo que sucede es que estoy probando con datos quemados para luego dinamizarlos puede ser en Pandas como mencioné o con una interfaz.

Lo que buscaba era automatizar los condicionales y eso lo conseguí con un vector aplanado y utilizando un diccionario, comparto la solución por si alguien lo cree útil.

```
arreglo = np.array([[ 5.6, -0.1, -0.8,  5.4, -0.4, -0.5, 5.3, -0.2, -0.4,  3.6, -0.1, -0.9,  3.6,
                     -0.3, -0.7,  3.5, -0.2, -0.7,  1.3,-0.1, -0.8,  1.3, -0.2, -0.7,  1.3, -0.1, -0.7]])
vector_total = arreglo.transpose() #-- Lista madre

caracteres_comunes = []
cc_dict = {}

# Obtener todos los valores de caracteres comunes
for x in range(len(datos)):
    if datos[x][1] == 'Columna':
        caracteres_comunes.append(datos[x][2])

# Aplanar lista
cc_list = list(set(caracteres_comunes))

# Definir diccionario
for y in cc_list:
    cc_dict[y] = [] 

# Popular diccionario con coordenadas de caracteres comunes
for z in range(len(datos)):
    if datos[z][1] == 'Columna':
        key = datos[z][2]
        cc_dict[key].extend([datos[z][6]-1, datos[z][7]-1, datos[z][8]-1])

# Recorrer diccionario
maxims = [0]
drift = [0]
for k in cc_dict:
    maxims.extend(max(abs(vector_total[cc_dict[k]])))

    drifts = (maxims[k]-maxims[k-1])/2.5
    drift.append(drifts)
```

Saludos cordiales,